# How to pass array of strings to a Java program?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

In:

```
public static void main (String [ ] args)
```

How to set the value parameter variable `args` of the `main` method as an array of String?

Comment: Are u asking how to pass data into the main method??While executing the java code you pass the value which would be accepted by String args using command line . eg java MyProg arg0 arg1

Comment: These are passed in from the command line.

Comment: Hi !. By my understand : this command line syntax : java MyProgram --arg1 --arg2 like means that in compiler will create variable String[] after it 'll call main method. String[] args = new String[] {"arg1 ", "arg2"};

Answer (score 3):

The args are optional command line values.

```
java MyProgram --arg1 --arg2
```

could be accessed as

```
args[0] == "--arg1"
args[1] == "--arg2"
```

Comment: Hi RyPope !.
By my understand : this command line syntax : 

java MyProgram --arg1 --arg2

like means that in compiler will create variable String[] after it 'll call main method.

String[] args = new String[] {"arg1 ", "arg2"};

Comment: Hi RyPope ! Thank you, but I don't have enough to do that !

Answer (score 1):

Value is passed as command line arguments.

For ex, you have this program`(Cmd.java)`:

```java
public class Cmd
{
  public static void main(String agrs[])
  {
    System.out.println("Values are:"+args[0]+" and "+args[1]);

    args[0]="New1";
    args[1]="New2";

    System.out.println("Modified values are:"+args[0]+" and "+args[1]);
  }
}
```

Compile it like:

```
javac Cmd.java
```

Execute it like:

```
java Cmd Value1 Value2
```

Output will be:

```
Values are Vaue1 and Value2
Modified values are New1 and New1
```

Hope you got the point!

**BONUS:**

If you don't pass any values during execution the program will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
You may want to handle that!

Read more about Command Line arguments at [The Java tutorials (Oracle docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)!

Comment: Hi Nivedita ! 

I'm understand how do it work, Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your java program in command line you can provide arguments to the executable:

> java MyClass arg0 arg1 arg2

Answer (score 0):

In Java the word `args` contains the [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) that are given in input to your program as an array of `String` Objects.

That is, if you run `java AnExample a b`, `args` will contain `["a", "b"]`.

So, if you want just to print out the contents of `args`, you can simply loop through them:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for( int i=1; i < args.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( args[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

For a deep explication of the Java `args` you can read this [interesting presentation](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/command-args.html) from Emory university.

Comment: Hi Alex! 

I'm understand how do it work.
Tks so much !

Comment: You're welcome, @thanphong37vn. Don't forget to accept the answer you think it fits the most ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an array of Strings when you call the program.

`java MyClass args0 args1 etc`

If you are using Eclipse then this is done under `Project->Run Configurations/Debug Configurations`. Click the `Arguments` tab and enter your arguments in the `Program arguments` box.

Comment: Hi James Fox! 

I'm understand how do it work, Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `String args[]` contains all the arguments you pass to a Java program when you start it with a command line.

Example command to launch a Java application:

> java MyApp arg1 arg2

What we have done in the example above is we passed 2 arguments to our `MyApp` java application ("arg1" and "arg2").
You can now use them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

yup..
just compile your code by

```
javac <class name> args0 args1 ..
```